# Spring Jar dependency Presedence

Tags: spring, maven

I have one Spring application(CustomerPort). In this I am using one open source jar(commons-lang.**2.4**). And my CustomerPort using other module, as jar, which using different version "commons-lang.**2.2**".

Since the other module using commons-lang.**2.2**, my application also refereeing modules opensource jar instead of commons-lang.**2.4**.

Could you plz let me how to exclude commons-lang.**2.2** in Pom.xml file

Answer (score 1):

use the `<scope>` tag to correct the scope of these transitive dependencies. Read [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) for more info on maven dependency scopes

Answer (score 1):

In the `pom.xml` for CustomerPort, where you specify the dependency on the other jar module, you can specify an exclusion for `commons-lang`. This will prevent Maven from bringing in the `commons-lang` transitive dependency from the other jar.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>otherModuleGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>otherModuleArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>otherModuleVersion</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>                   
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Verify that its doing the right thing by running `mvn dependency:tree` in CustomerPort.

More info on excluding transitive dependencies [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)